# No output when QEMU shell script is executed

Tags: scripts, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I've got a problem which there's no output in the terminal when I run the following command:

```
sudo ./windows10vm.sh
```

The script that I used come from [This tutorial](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=212692) from the linux mint forums which I've slightly modified

```
#!/bin/bash

configfile=/etc/vfio-pci.cfg
vmname="windows10virt"

vfiobind() {
   dev="$1"
        vendor=$(cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/vendor)
        device=$(cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/device)
        if [ -e /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver ]; then
                echo $dev > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver/unbind
        fi
        echo $vendor $device > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id

}


if ps -A | grep -q $vmname; then
   echo "$vmname is already running." &
   exit 1

else

   cat $configfile | while read line;do
   echo $line | grep ^# >/dev/null 2>&1 && continue
      vfiobind $line
   done

# use pulseaudio
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa

cp /usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd /tmp/my_vars.fd

qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -name $vmname,process=$vmname \
  -machine type=q35,accel=kvm \
  -cpu host,\
  -smp 4,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1 \
  -enable-kvm \
  -m 12G \
  -mem-path /run/hugepages/kvm \
  -mem-prealloc \
  -balloon none \
  -rtc clock=host,base=localtime \
  -vga none \
  -nographic \
  -serial none \
  -parallel none \
  -soundhw hda \
  -usb -usbdevice host:1b1c:1a0c -usbdevice host:1b1c:1b2f \
  -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,multifunction=on \
  -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.1 \
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_CODE-pure-efi.fd \
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/tmp/my_vars.fd \
  -boot order=dc \
  -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi \
  -drive id=disk0,if=virtio,cache=none,format=raw,file=/home/james/windows10.img \
  -drive file=/home/user/ISOs/win10.iso,id=isocd,format=raw,if=none -device scsi-cd,drive=isocd \
  -drive file=/home/user/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.112.iso,id=virtiocd,format=raw,if=none -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=virtiocd \
  -netdev type=tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,vhost=on \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=00:16:3e:00:01:01

   exit 0
fi
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Does  `/etc/vfio-pci.cfg` exist and is it empty?